# Условия вхождения в площадь кольца

Tags: python, геометрия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ещё не учитывал нижнюю часть окружности -__-

при x=1,а y=4..6 -> выводит,что находится на границе

при y=1,а x=4..6 -> выводит,что находится на границе

```
from math import *
print('x=')
x=int(input())
print('y=')
y=int(input())
sq = pi*(7*7-3*3)
r = x*x+y*y
print(r)
if r < sq and x > 2 and x < 8 and y > 2 and y < 8: #and (x >= 0 and y > 2 and y < 8) or (y >= 0 and x > 2 and x < 8) and x<8 and y<8:
    print('Inside')
elif r > sq or (x < 3 and y < 3) or (y >7 and x > 7) : #or x > 7 or y > 7 or x < 3 or y:
    print('Outside')
else:
    print('Line')
```

Comment: а в уравнение окружности  не пробовали подставлять x и y ?

Comment: А для чего?Там же нужен радиус.

Comment: если выполняется x^2 + y^2 <= r^2 значит лежит внутри, если нет то снаружи. очевидно для большей окружности должно лежать внутри, для меньшей снаружи. Если оба условия выполнятся, то внутри кольца.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
inner_radius = 3
outer_radius = 7
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
distance_to_zero = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
if (distance_to_zero > inner_radius and distance_to_zero < outer_radius)
   print("inside", x, y)
elif (distance_to_zero < inner_radius or distance_to_zero > outer_radius)
   print("outside")
else
   print("on line")
```

Площадь кольца не нужна совершенно.

Comment: Спасибо,понял :)